# VS Object browser will not stop refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am working in VS 2008 SP1 professional. The solution has 8 projects. On of the project has 9 service references. It is nothing to crazy. The problem I am having is when I open the Object Browser to view the services, the object browser endless refreshes. This makes it very hard to use because the select item and view jumps to the top of the list ever few seconds. I have tried doing builds, closing and reopening VS and the object browser. I can not come up with a good answer as to why it is doing this. The only thing that seems to work is to let it endless refresh for about 5mins and the problem seems to "fix" itself. Does anyone know what the object browser is doing? Is there a way to get it to stop?

This only seems to happen after I update a service reference.

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0):

Yep, i have similar problem, but caused remote service (located out of intranet).
That is why we have copied web reference as regular .CS files into special project, so manual refreshing is now possible. We have assumed that interface changes so rarely.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly it is not applicable. The services change too much. At least now while we are in development anyways.